# A program that will solve a log math prob, using Java

Tags: java, function, math

I have a programming competition coming up and I am solving last years problems as revision for the competition, i came across a simple program however it requires math which unfortunately i am very bad at.

Here is the question:

> Given a positive integer **n**,find the odd integer **o** and the
>   non-negative integer **p** such that **n=o2^p** (**o** multiplied by 2
>   to the power **p**)
>
> the first line of the input file contains exactly one positive integer
>   **d** equal to the number of test cases,**1<=d<=10**. the data set follows. Each data set consists of exactly one line containing 
>   exactly one integer **n, 1<=n<=10^6**
>
> Sample output
>
> 2  //d value of number of test cases
>   24 // value of n
>   27 // value of n
>
> Sample output
>   3 3  // first 3 is value of o, 2nd 3 is value of p
>   7 7  // first 7 is value of o, 2nd 7 is value of p
>
> the "//" part should not be in the output or input

and this is what I have done so far, I got everything right except for the formula I need to use for the equation to solve correctly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double n = 0, d = 0, o = 0, p = 0;

    double x = 1;

    //START INPUT
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //input d, number of times program repeats

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of times you want to run the test(no more than 10)");
    d = input.nextDouble();

    //check the validity of d
    while((d > 10) || (d<1)){
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
         System.out.println("Enter another value for d");
         d = input.nextDouble();
    }



    while(x <= d){

            x++;

            System.out.println("enter a value for n");
            n = input.nextDouble();
    //check the validity of n
        while((n > 1000000) || (n<1)){
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            System.out.println("Enter Another Value for n");
            n = input.nextDouble();
        }
        //Calculates
        p = Math.log(n) / Math.log(2.0);
        o = n / Math.pow(p, 2);
    //STOP CALCULATE

    //PRINTS    
        System.out.println(o + " " + p);
        }

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Math.pow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).

Comment: The result for 27 would not be (7,7) actually. You might add 28 with (7,2) as another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many different ways. For programming contests I usually go with a simple approach when there are small numbers: bruteforce! Maybe not a perfect answer to your question, but keep it in mind when doing other tasks at the competition: working is good enough, choose the first solution you can come up with and try implementing it. At least that's true for most competitions I've been at, where it's about doing as many tasks as possible within a given time frame.

For the formula **n = o2<sup>p</sup>**,
with **o** odd and **p** > 0, and 1 <= **n** <= 10<sup>6</sup>,
we can see that 2<sup>p</sup> will always be *at least* 2.
That means that o should be below half of n, so we only need to search for o's up to half of the value we're given. And we only need to check odd values.

And then one can just try different p values for the chosen o. If the result is higher than n, we should try the next value of o.

javacode:

```
public void calc(int n) {
    for (int o = 1; o <= n / 2; o += 2) {
        int p = 1;
        while (true) {
            int test = o * (int) Math.pow(2, p);
            if (test == n) { // solution found
                System.out.println("o:" + o + ", p:" + p);
                return;
            }
            if (test > n) break; // total value too high, lets start with another o
            p++;
        }
    }
}
```

Stepping through this with you input of n=24:
o = 1, p = 1  => 2
o = 1, p = 2  => 4
o = 1, p = 3  => 8
o = 1, p = 4  => 16
o = 1, p = 5  => 32, too high, try another o
o = 3, p = 1  => 6
o = 3, p = 2  => 12
o = 3, p = 3  => 24, TADA!

Different bruteforce methods may be to instead start with the value of p, or to instead divide n by different values of 2<sup>p</sup> until you get an odd integer.

Comment: i tried the code  but eclipse asks me to put a ";" after pow(2, p) but then i get an error after the "return" which says "unreachable code"

Comment: @user3495129 it's just pseudocode, you will need to change it a bit for it to work in java. The idea of the code should be clear, though.

Comment: i tried the code and i got it to work, when i inputted the numbers 24,48,52 the program worked, BUT when i tried  a number like 50 i get o = 23 and p =2, which is wrong i tried removing the "/2" from "o<n/2" however i still get o = 23 and p =2..........any thoughts?

Comment: @user3495129 updated my code. It was supposed to be <=n/2, not <n/2. Also made the code java for you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is repeatedly divide by 2:

```
function removeTwo(n)
    o, p := n, 0
    while o % 2 == 0
        o, p := o/2, p+1
    return o, p
```

I'll leave it to you to translate to Java.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually does not involve sooo much math. It's rather about bit twiddling.

It helps to know that each value 2^p is equal to `(1<<p)`. Knowing this, you can first compute the highest bit that is set in `n`. For example

```
n = 24 =  11000 (binary) : Highest bit is 4
n = 36 : 100100 (binary) : Highest bit is 5
```

Then you can start with this bit position as a candiate for `p`, decrease this value until you find that the equation is solvable. When you reach zero, then the input value `n` must have been odd. This could be detected explicitly at the beginning, if desired.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FindFactors
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int n=0; n<100; n++)
        {
            System.out.println("For "+n+" : "+Arrays.toString(findFactors(n)));
        }
    }

    private static int[] findFactors(int n)
    {
        int p = highestBit(n);
        while (p >= 0)
        {
            int twoPowP = (1 << p);
            int c = n / twoPowP;
            if (c * twoPowP == n)
            {
                return new int[]{c,p};
            }
            p--;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static int highestBit(int n)
    {
        int b = 0;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n >>= 1;
            b++;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```